# how to only show progress bar of the master node of tqdm in distributed training?

Tags: pytorch, tqdm

tqdm flushes a lot in distributed training setting (`torch.distributed.run`) Is there a way to only display the bar from master node?

Answer (score 2):

You can switch it off by setting `disable=True` parameter for non-master processes, for example:

```py
# ...
    
master_process = ddp_rank == 0

# ...
    
for epoch in range(epoch_num):
  with tqdm(dataloader, disable=not master_process) as pbar:    
    # ...
```